# pandas - how to convert a column to a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, time

Hello I have pandas df as shows above. The `date` Column has to to be converted.

So I wrote this code:

```py
df2['date']= pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

And I have this error:

```
time data test_2021-03-01 02:30:02.237441 doesn't match format specified
```

i don't know how to proceed
Thanks

[image: pandas df]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pass `errors`

```
df2['date']= pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors = 'coerce')
```

Update `split`

```
s = df2['date'].astype(str).str.split('_').str[-1]; 
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors = 'coerce')
```

Comment: THANKS   So from now, i can split my column ?

Comment: @phildrav yes you can  df2['date2'] = df2['date'].str.split('_').str[-1]; df2['date']= pd.to_datetime(df2['date2'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors = 'coerce')

Comment: df2['date2'] = df2['date'].str.split('_').str[-1]  returns me an error  : AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @phildrav adding astype(str)

Comment: like this?  df2['date2'] = df2['date'].str.split('_').str[-1].astype(str)

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that your data has timestamp mixed with some other things. You can try extract it first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['time data test_2021-03-01 02:30:02.237441']})

ext_time = df['date'].str.extract('(\d{4}-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+)')[0]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ext_time, errors='coerce',  format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Output:

```
                        date
0 2021-03-01 02:30:02.237441
```